# Convert Pandas dataframe to format suitable for PostgreSQL COPY ... FROM STDIN

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

Given a Pandas dataframe, how can it be converted to a form suitable for PostgreSQL's COPY FROM STDIN (ideally in TEXT mode)?

A naive way would be:

```py
text = df.to_csv(
    index=False,
    header=False,
    sep='\t',
    na_rep=r'\N',
)
```

but this won't work in several cases. For example, when there is a tab in the data itself - it wraps such fields in quotes instead of putting a backslash in front of it, which is what's required according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.9.2

Note the data can have NAs, which should be converted to NULLs, and it can have tabs, quotes, newlines etc, which should be preserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that is a bit less naive, although I can't speak to its efficiency:

```py
def to_postgresql_copy_from_text(df):
    def escape(text):
        return (
            text.replace('\\', '\\\\')
            .replace('\n', '\\n')
            .replace('\r', '\\r')
            .replace('\t', '\\t')
        )

    return ''.join(
        '\t'.join(
            '\\N' if field is pd.NA else escape(str(field)) for field in row
        ) + '\n'
        for row in df.itertuples(index=False)
    )
```

which can be used as

```py
text = to_postgresql_copy_from_text(df)
```